# How can I check if an email has been exchanged in cleartext?

Tags: security, ssl, email

How can I check that an email that I received has been transmitted in encrypted form between all MTAs by which it passed? This is not a question about end-to-end encryption, i.e., it's OK that the MTAs saw the message in the clear; but I'd like to know if the message was exchanged in cleartext at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be checked by inspecting the "with XXX" part of the "Received" headers of the email, to check if the methods XXX are secure (see methods here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/mail-parameters/mail-parameters.xhtml#mail-parameters-7). This is what is done by the Paranoia Thunderbird extension in its source code: https://github.com/gjedeer/paranoia/blob/master/content/overlay.js